# Graph data structure questions

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, pseudocode

I have problem designing pseudo-code for these problems.
It is not an assignment problem.
All I know about them is they have something to do with GRAPH data structure.

1. Describe an `O(n+m)-time` algorithm for computing all the connected components of an undirected graph `G` with n vertices and m edges.

   (I am guessing this has something to do with traversal Breadth First Search (BFS), but correct me if I am wrong.).

   ```
   Input Graph G
   Output sequence of connected vertices with edges

   List = empty list

   for all u in G.vertices
       setLabel(u, UNEXPLORED)

   for all e in G.edges
       setLabel(e, UNEXPLORED)

   For all v in G.vertices
       if getLabel(v) = UNEXPLORED
           BFS (G,v,List)

   BFS(G,s,List)

   Object A = vertex1, vertex2, edge

   L0 = new empty sequence
   L0.addLast(s)
   setLabel(s,VISITED)

   i=0

   while Li is not Empty
       L(i+1) = new empty sequence
       for all v in L(i).elements
           for all incidentEdges(v)
               if getLabel(e) = UNEXPLORED
                   w = opposite(v,e)
                   if getLabel(w) = UNEXPLORED
                       setLabel(e,DISCOVERY)
                       setLabel(w,VISITED)
                       setVertex1(A,v)
                       setVertex2(A,w)
                       setEdge(A,e)
                       List.addLast(A)
                       L(i+1).addLast(w)
                   else
                       setLabel(e,CROSS)
       i = i + 1
   ```
2. Say that an n-vertex directed acyclic graph G is compact.
   If there is some way of numbering the vertices of G with integers from 0 to n-1 such that G contains the edge (i,j) if and only if i < j, for all (i , j) in [0,n-1], Give an O(n^2)-time algorithm for detecting if G is compact.

   (Again, I am guessing this has something to do with topological ordering, but I am not sure how to implement it).
3. Say a connected graph G is biconnected if it contains no vertex whose removal would divide G into 2 or more connected components.

   Give an O(n+m)-time algorithm for adding at most n edges to a connected graph G, with n>= 3 vertices and m>=(n-1) edges, to guarantee that G is biconnected. (Probably spanning forest?).

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically are you having issues with? This type of question is hard to answer because it is too open ended. Also, if you have different questions, you should ask them in different threads, along with details.

Comment: I didn't put them in different thread because all of them are "sort of" linked together.

Comment: @orangeoctopus, I am looking for advice on how to design pseudocode for those problems. I have a rough guess on each of them (specified in brackets for each question), but I tend to think they are wrong.

Comment: How can we help other than providing you the pseudocode?

Comment: @orangeoctopus: probably explanation if my guess is wrong.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat : I just did another reasonable attempt at each of them. I will try to upload it now (having trouble with the tags).

Comment: @Mitch Wheat : I can't add a code tag to it. IF I add my solution, the formatting is all messy. I will try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had fun with these problems! At least, 2 and 3.

1)
    I'm not sure I fully understand, but I figure by "compute the connected components" you mean "build subsets of the vertices such that each subset is a connected component". If so, I think BFS or DFS would work depending on how you manage memory (ie. how you mark vertices you've already visited).

2)
    [Edited]Here's an algorithm which, used on any acyclic directed graph, should number the vertices according to the "compact" definition and detect if the graph is in fact compact (ie. contains **all** edges (i, j) such that i < j for all (i, j) in [0, n-1]).

1. Find all vertices with no incoming edges (since the graph is acyclic, we know there will be at least one of these).
   1a. If there are more than one, terminate algorithm: the graph is not compact.
2. Assign a number to it, starting from the lowest number available (0, for the first iteration).
3. Remove this vertex from the graph, along with all edges outgoing from it.
4. Go back to step 1, and repeat until all vertices are gone. If we reach that point without the algorithm terminating, then the graph is compact.

(This is also O(n^2), btw - n searches over n vertices to find vertices without incoming edges - although this is only worst-case)
At the end of this, all vertices will be numbered such that if it has incoming edges, the nodes from which they come will have a lower number than itself.

3)
    Assuming the graph is already connected, here is an algorithm to make it biconnected:

1. Find all vertices with only one edge (ie. endpoints).
2. Arbitrarily select one of these.
3. Draw edges from this selected vertex to all the other endpoint vertices.
   (I think this actually fits O(n). One search over n vertices to find endpoints, and we add less than n edges, since you can't have a connected graph consisting entirely of endpoints.)

Voila! A biconnected graph! Remove any endpoint vertex, and the original connected graph is still intact; remove any other vertex, and we know that each segment is still connected through the endpoints.

Comment: G contains the edge (i,j) **if and only if** i < j

Comment: Yes, but you're choosing the i and j (you label the vertices). Can you think of a counter-example? An acyclical graph that is not compact? I still can't... :/

Comment: Yes, every directed graph that is not a tournament.

Comment: @Cephron : Thanks for your help. I am still trying to digest your answer. For question 2, I try to design any DAG, and you are right, can't find any DAG that is not compact (because there is always a cycle in DAG).

Comment: @Per: Here's a trivial graph which is not a tournament: ( X -> X -> X <- X -> X -> X <- X <- X ), numbered according to compactness: (0 -> 3 -> 6 <- 1 -> 4 -> 7 <- 5 <- 2).
Each edge goes from a node with lower number to a node with higher number...

Comment: It's missing, e.g., the edge from 0 to 6. **if and only if**

Comment: Ah! You are right! I laugh at myself for not understanding the "if and only if" even after you bolded it. Back to the drawing board, I guess...
Butbut wait a minute...that seems to contradict the the definition of it being an acyclic graph?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong(I am newbie in graph). DAG must have something that look like a cycle but it is not actually a cycle. Hence aren't you suppose to add 2 -> 0 to Cephron's graph?

Comment: @Gippyz: the other was around, I think. Acyclic here means that you can't have an edge pointing to an ancestor node (a node which points to your parent node). Complicated stuff to try to get across without pictures...
Ah, ok. Yes. I think my algorithm happens to still work for assigning numbers appropriately, but it needs to count edges as it goes. Editing...